# a histogram life datatype in objective c / iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, arrays

I have an array with many numbers, which I would like to convert into a histogram like array where for each number I have the number of occurrence of this number in the array. I tried to look everywhere if there are any APIs for xcode but could not find.

What would be the best way to go about that?

Thanks!!!

Comment: NSCountedSet. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
```

Where array is the combined array containing all your elements.